# Highcharts failing to get parsed with json into django templates

Tags: json, django, highcharts, django-views, django-templates

Hello im trying to embed highcharts into my django code but with no success.
i tried the usual hardcoding of the data into the templates and it worked.
Then i tried parsing the data from the django views and it failed to work.
Next was using json to parse the data and that one as well doesnt work yet everywhere its taken to be the best option

Below is my views.py file

```
def totals_mapper(request):
    template_name = "stats/totals_barchart.html"

    cats = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"]
    the_totals = [12, 45, 88, 70, 43, 31, 19, 99]

    context = {"cats": cats, "the_totals": the_totals}

    # THE JSON EXAMPLE CHARTS
    dataset = ['cats', 'the_totals']

    return render(request, template_name, {"dataset": dataset})
```

Below is the html file...

```html
<div id="container" class="container-fluid"></div>

<script language="javascript">

    Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Variation of regions and different total submissions from there'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [
            {% for entry in dataset %}'{{entry.cats}}'{% if not forloop.last %},{%endif %} {%endfor %}
        ],
        title: {
            text: 'Regions in the country', 
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Number of total submissions',
        },
        labels: {
            overflow: 'justify'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' millions'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        x: -40,
        y: 80,
        floating: true,
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor:
            Highcharts.defaultOptions.legend.backgroundColor || '#FFFFFF',
        shadow: true
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'the totals',
        data: [{% for entry in dataset %}{{ entry.the_totals}}{% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}{% endfor %}]
    },]
});

</script>

<!-- Chartjs libraries -->
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>
```

Nothing shows in the browser and im really stuck. help

Comment: Are you sure that your JS config is correct? It looks like a mix of JS and Django.

Comment: Oh man thanks alot for your comment. Honestly im no good at JS so i wont lie that i know where the issue is arising from at least for that which i posted

Comment: Makuma - Have you seen this article? It should help you understand how to implement Highcharts & Django - https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/create-a-dashboard-using-highcharts-and-django/

Comment: i followed that article some few days ago and the errors i was getting were for the placeholder jinja-like templating in the javascript code. It seemed as though js wasnt recognising things like {%for x in xx%}{{x}}{%endfor%} As i kept getting tag error this and that. I also tried saving the highcharts js code in a .js file instead of .html but still got no resolve. I have searched everywhere and posted everywhere and really things are not that good on my end as per this issue as i feel very frustrated

Comment: Look at this issue that i opened on the same issue on github https://github.com/hellomukama/helpNeeded/issues/1

Comment: But comparing the code from the tutorial which I shared to your code I cannot found any mixing of JS and Django, as I can see in your code. It is definitely a bad pattern.

Comment: What do i do now?

Comment: 1. Remove all Python commends from the Highcharts config, 2. Attach the Highcharts scripts BEFORE the Highcharts config